# Error: Invalid Default Value from move Data in Ubuntu mariadb to Centos mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I have to **move Ubuntu mariadb(10.1.41) data(78GB)** to **CentOS mariadb(5.5.64)**.

I used to mysqldump and export on heidiSQL, But every try is failed.

I think problem is that column 's default is current_timestamp.
So, I did test.

here is test query:

```
CREATAE TABLE test (
  ts INT(11),
  ts2 DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Result is

> "SQL ERROR(1067) : Invalid default value for 'test'"

So, I tried : edit configure /etc/my.cnf

> sql-mode="ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

and

> sql-mode=""

and

> sql-mode="NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

But, Everything is Failed. what should I do??

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB 5.5 `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is not supported as default for column type `DATETIME`.

Workarounds:

- Update MariaDB Server to 10.x
- change column type from `DATETIME` to
  `TIMESTAMP`